# mmap: effect of other processes writing to a file previously mapped read-only

Tags: c, mmap

I am trying to understand what happens when a file, which has been mapped into memory by the `mmap` system call, is subsequently written to by other processes.

I have `mmap`ed memory with `PROT_READ` protection in "process A". If I close the underlying file descriptor in process A, and another process later writes to that file (not using `mmap`; just a simple redirection of stdout to the file using `>` in the shell), is the `mmap`ed memory in the address space of process A affected? Given that the pages are read-only, I would expect them not to change. However, process A is being terminated by `SIGBUS` signals as a result of invalid memory accesses (`Non-existent physical address at address 0x[...]`) when trying to parse the mapped memory. I am suspecting that this is stemming from writes to the backing file by other processes. Would setting `MAP_PRIVATE` be sufficient to completely protect this memory from other processes?

Comment: Whats worse than seeing the changed content is having a changed length. It will make you fault on read access to the area behind the truncation (and the truncation might be at offset 0)

Comment: @eckes : Thanks, I think that is the source of the `SIGBUS` signals my process received after another processed truncated the file it had mapped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I close the underlying file descriptor in process A,

closing the file descriptor doesn't change anything at all

> another process later writes to that file (not using mmap; just a simple redirection of stdout to the file using > in the shell), is the mmaped memory in the address space of process A affected?

It may be. The manpage of `mmap(2)` says:

```
 MAP_PRIVATE
    ...
    It is  unspecified  whether changes made to the file
    after the mmap() call are visible in the mapped region.
```

In practice, changes made by other processes seem to be reflected in the content of the mmaped region, at least for regular files.

> However, process A is being terminated by SIGBUS signals as a result of invalid memory accesses (Non-existent physical address at address 0x[...]) when trying to parse the mapped memory.

I'm expecting that to happen when you truncate a mmaped file.

> Would setting `MAP_PRIVATE` be sufficient to completely protect this memory from other processes?

No, `MAP_PRIVATE` only prevent modifications to the memory from being carried through to the backing file, not the reverse.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  So it sounds like `mmap` is not the right tool for reading (and preserving in memory) the current state of a file, when that file might be modified by other processes before the memory has been completely read by the process which created the map?

Comment: hurd seems to have a `MAP_COPY` for that, but that's not supported on Linux/BSD/Solaris/etc. You can read more about it [here](https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/map_copy.html).

Comment: @mosvy should the syncing be done manually now ?